# Update complex dict with another dict with different formatting

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have two `python2` dictionaries and I want to run `dict1.update(dict2)`. Unfortunately right now I am getting the error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

When I try doing that. Now I need a way to transform first or the second dictionary to make the update successful. First dictionary looks like this:

`{'xpos': 1000012783L, 'tags': [{'searchParameters': None, 'category': u'C Discovery Tags', 'tagGuid': u'VT0000068_112783_f000819_sf063'}], 'functionalData': [], 'notes': [], 'selectedMainTranscriptId': None, 'alt': u'A', 'guid': u'SV0000023_112783_f000819_sf063', 'ref': u'G', 'id': 23}`

Second looks like that (It is actually retrieved from `JSONField` from a `Django` model):

`{"liftedOverGenomeVersion": null, "pos": 12783, "predictions": {"splice_ai": null, "eigen": 0.299, "revel": null, "mut_taster": null, "fathmm": null, "phastcons_100_vert": null, "polyphen": null, "dann":
0.2757730705502398, "sift": null, "cadd": 0.828, "metasvm": null, "primate_ai": null, "gerp_rs": null, "mpc": null}, "clinvar": {"alleleId": null, "clinicalSignificance": null, "variationId": null, ...}`

I verified the types of the dictionaries, and they are both `<type 'dict'>`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is `null`?  The code works for me after defining `null = None`, removing the `...` and adding a missing brace..

Comment: There is a field in my `Django` model that is of type `JSONField`. It was saved probably with some empty field in it, and so when I retrieve the field that stores json, that is the dictionary that is generated. So, it is very weird: pretty much Django returns me `null` that is non-existent in `python` and I do not even know how to remove it.

Comment: That is not what I mean. What does `print (dict2['liftedOverGenomeVersion'], type(dict2['liftedOverGenomeVersion']))` print?

Comment: Or just `print (null, type(null))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was the issue. It happened in the following way: First we had `TextField` in `Django` model and were saving json into it, which required `json.dumps(dict_to_save)`. But then we switched to `JSONField` and this `json.dumps` started causing the issue introducing `null`s into the database. It is not an answer to my question, but something to be aware of. Rather hard to identify bug.

Answer (score 2):

You have 'None' in the first dictionary and 'Null' in the other dictionary.

**There is no 'Null' in Python.**

Fixing this solved the problem.

```
d1 = {'xpos': 1000012783,'tags': [{'searchParameters': None, 'category': 'C Discovery Tags', 'tagGuid': 'VT0000068_112783_f000819_sf063'}], 'functionalData': [], 'notes': [], 'selectedMainTranscriptId': None, 'alt': 'A', 'guid': 'SV0000023_112783_f000819_sf063', 'ref': 'G', 'id': 23}



d2 = {"liftedOverGenomeVersion": None, "pos": 12783, "predictions": {"splice_ai": None, "eigen": 0.299, "revel": None, "mut_taster": None, "fathmm": None, "phastcons_100_vert": None, "polyphen": None, "dann":0.2757730705502398, "sift": None, "cadd": 0.828, "metasvm": None, "primate_ai": None, "gerp_rs": None, "mpc": None}, "clinvar": {"alleleId": None, "clinicalSignificance": None, "variationId": None}}


d1.update(d2)

print(d1)
```

[image]

Comment: It is strange that `Django` `JSONField` gets such results. I would expect it to care about `null` (and other) issues.